# Error while using postgresql on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have installed `postgresql` and then I type

`rails new TravelApp --database=postgresql`

`bundle install` ,  `rails s`

However, when I visit [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000/), it shows this error.

[image]

Should I edit some configurations ?

Comment: You just need to do exactly what the error message is telling you to do: `bin/rake db:create db:migrate`. If that fails you may need to edit `config/database.yml` to provide the correct database connection parameters.

Comment: yes, you are right thanks. But what is that mean?

Comment: It means that rails has not set up the database yet. In other words, the schema, tables, indexes, etc. have not been created for your application yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Then start rails server.

Comment: yes, it work perfect. But why I need to type that? When I use default databases(`sqlite3`), I didn't need to type this.

Comment: You need to run rake db:create to create database and rake db:migrate to add database tables with schema if available. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project

Comment: Even with sqlite you have to run db:migrate after creating a migration (although rails will create the initial empty database schema for you). If you don't run migrations then any code referencing a table/field/etc created by a migration is going to fail.

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if it included additional explanation, like what you posted in the comments.

Comment: ok I got it. So basically I need to run `db:migrate` after creating a new app.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from your console:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

This will be enough.